# How to use the menu strip to show all open MDI forms C#

Tags: c#, mdichild, mdiparent

[image: Image of my form]

I need to display all open MDI forms when I click the `window` button in the menu strip. It should drop down and give you an option to select the active one. This is probably some simple answer but I have looked in so many places.

Comment: just simply add new menuitem to the window menu item whenever you add new child form and remove it when you close that one.

Comment: That can work but my lecturer showed a much easier way of doing it. I think it was a property that she set. Thanks for the reply

Comment: [Just RTFM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171654%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want this:

[image: pic]

which you get by setting the property `MdiWindowListItem` on the menu strip

[image: menu]

Comment: Thank you so much. That is exactly what I was looking for:D